# Replace Any Number in a URL using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to fix all the links on a blog but instead of editing each post manually I decided to write a simple script to do it automatically. How can I use jquery to replace an unknown number in a link? In this case I'm trying to remove it to fix the formatting.

Here's the HTML

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/2016/10/%20http://www.newlink.com">LINK</a>
```

Script

```
$("a").each( function() {
   this.href = this.href.replace("http://www.example.com/XXXX/XX/%20","");
});
```

Final output should be

```
<a href="http://www.newlink.com/anypost.html">LINK</a>
```

Comment: You want to replace only numbers in a link ? or anything other than "http://www.newlink.com" ?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't specific. Basically I want to remove http://www.example.com/2016/10/%20 from the url. The new link is not fixed.

Comment: Why not just do `this.href = this.href.substring(this.href.indexOf('http://www.newlink.com'));`. Then you don't need to worry about numbers at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it using RegExp. Basically it's - replace everything before the first %20 including the %20.

```js
$("a").each( function() {
   this.href = this.href.replace(/^.+%20?/, '');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="http://www.example.com/2016/10/%20http://www.newlink.com">LINK</a>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need. Thank you!